# About the interpretation of line integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been asked to compute the line integral of the function $f(x,y)=xy$ over the elipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2=1$ counterclockwise orientated. My doubt is if this means that i have to compute the surface area of the region of the space given by $f(x,y)$ or if just have to compute the integral resulting. Because in the second case I end up getting a result of zero because the volume over the $xy$ plane equals the volume above it, while in the first one I guess the right approach would be to compute that line integral but just over the first quadrant of the elipse and then multiply it by 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Line integral** over the ellipsis" means that you have to integrate the values that $f(x,y)$ takes on when $(x,y)$ is tied to stay on the ellipsis.
Otherwise one should say "**Surface integral** of .. in the region bounded by ..".
Now, since $f(x,y)=xy$ is anti-symmetric (vs. the axis), and the ellipsis is instead symmetric, the integral will be $0$, in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with *"surface area of the region of the space given by $f(x,y)$"*. If you want a geometrical interpretation, it is the surface area of the "curved wall" with the given curve (ellipse) as base and with (local) height $f(x,y)$. When this height is negative, the surface area is counted negative as well, just like with the normal Riemann integral.

So you can simply calculate it as a line integral but with this interpretation, you are expecting $0$ because the curve is completely symmetric w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ and the function $f(x,y)=xy$ will have as much surface area above as below the $xy$-plane, with the ellipse as base, thus canceling out all contributions from the four quadrants.